# What's the best way of writing the float value to ModbusServerContext

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm using the [pymodbus](https://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus) library for creating the Modbus server. I've discovered all examples which you can find [here](https://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/tree/master/examples). I faced with problem related to writing float value on the server (slave) side. There is an `updating_writer` function in which I want to write the float value = `22.34` to 2 holding resitors:

```
...
    def updating_writer(a):
        context  = a[0]
        register = 3
        slave_id = 0x00
        address  = 0x0
        builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder(endian=Endian.Little)
        builder.add_32bit_float(22.34)
        res = builder.build()
        context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, res)

    store = ModbusSlaveContext(
        di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
        co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
        hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
        ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100))
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
...
```

But when I have a connection from Modbus master (client) and try to read these 2 registor I get an error:

```
...
    File "/home/workstation/devel/modbus_example/env_modbus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymodbus/server/async.py", line 83, in _send
        pdu = self.framer.buildPacket(message)
      File "/home/workstation/devel/modbus_example/env_modbus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymodbus/transaction.py", line 354, in buildPacket
        data = message.encode()
      File "/home/workstation/devel/modbus_example/env_modbus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymodbus/register_read_message.py", line 71, in encode
        result += struct.pack('>H', register)
    struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer
```

How I should write the float value to some context? I cannot find any examples.

Comment: Check out this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pymodbus/X4vtEg9Hq10